# Java <-> C <-> Fortran

Tags: c, linker, java-native-interface, fortran

I have a slight problem. I am trying to compile a Java program interfacing with a C program, which then further interfaces with a FORTRAN 77 program. Basically, Java, through JNI, using a C program which uses LAPACK (the FORTRAN version)

The C program works fine by itself, interfacing with the FORTRAN 77 program as it should, but when I run the test program in Java, the linking between Fortran and C is broken.

I compile the C program like so:

```
gcc -c -fPIC -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/include/linux -llapack -lblas -lm Optibox.c
gcc -shared -o libOptibox.so Optibox.o
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH} java Optibox
```

It returns the error:

```
java: symbol lookup error: /home/christian/workspace/testJNI4/libOptibox.so: undefined symbol: dsytrf_
```

Which comes into play because of this snippet of code:

```
static long dsytrf(char UPLO, long N, double* A, long LDA, long* IPIV, double* WORK, long LWORK)
{
    extern void dsytrf_(char* UPLOp, long* Np, double* A, long* LDAp, long* IPIV, double* WORK, long* LWORKp, long* infop);
    long info;
    dsytrf_(&UPLO, &N, A, &LDA, IPIV, WORK, &LWORK, &info);
    return info;
}
```

This function works just fine if I simply make a C program testing the function, but upon using Java, LAPACK is no longer linked.

So I suppose the question is: How do I make the Java compiler link properly in this instance?

EDIT:
I've found a solution at least for now. I changed the linker statement to also link in the BLAS, LAPACK and MATRIX libraries themselves. This appears to solve the issue entirely, but I am not convinced of its elegance. I will try the library path suggestion given by Idav1s.

```
gcc -shared -o libOptibox.so Optibox.o liblapack.so libblas.so libm.so
```

This required that I found the libraries within /usr/lib and copied them to my compile directory, but at least it works!

Comment: Where are the Java and Fortran components?  The only module shown in the build is that which compiles `Optibox.c` to `libOptibox.so`.

Comment: `Java <-> C <-> Fortran`? Gah! I wouldn't want to be in your shoes

Comment: Yeah, it makes you go all upside down.

Which I suspect in your case would actually be helpful so you could get the right way up again. :)

Seriously though, it's gonna get worse. We're adding MATLAB on top of it as well. MATLAB <-> Java <-> C <-> FORTRAN as well as, through MEX files, MATLAB <-> C <-> FORTRAN.

Is fun times!

Comment: liblapack is what?  Fortran or Java?  Maybe it is both?  Anyway, where is `dsytrf_` implemented?

Comment: LAPACK is programmed in FORTRAN 77. dsytrf_ is a part of LAPACK, it factorizes a matrix into a lower and diagonal matrix to be solved with dsytrs_ using LDL**T.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your LAPACK and blas libs to `java.library.path`:

```
java -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/lapack:<other paths> Optibox
```

Adding them to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is sometimes not enough.

EDIT: Your link statement is also incorrect. It should be:

```
gcc -shared -fPIC -o libOptibox.so Optibox.o -llapack -lblas -lm
```

The linker flags are irrelevant when building `Optibox.o`.  The `libOptibox.so` lib needs the other libs.  Otherwise it'll never find them at load time.

Comment: I will try this a bit later. Thanks for the answer! I have found a solution, however. I will add my own answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

This really belongs as a comment, instead of an answer, but I can't find the comment button!  So anyway, this from the gcc man page, re: the "-shared" flag: "Produce a shared object which can then be linked .... For predicatable results, you must also specify the same set of options that were used to generate code (-fpic, -fPIC, or model suboptions) when you specify this option."

There's no "-fPIC" in your gcc link statement.  That's where I would start.  (Actually, where I would *really* start is hopping onto the desk of whoever wants you to write this awful code and screaming at them until they change their mind.)

Comment: Well spotted. I'll try to add that as well. There will be no changing of minds, however. This is absolutely needed, sadly. Even I can see why. :|

Comment: Due to this being stated in the documentation, it probably doesn't hurt, but I can tell you it doesn't solve the problem either.